# How can I check how many people have gotten a certain tag badge?

Tags: support

Badge information pages have an indication of how many people have been awarded the badge; and if you count the number of users (or users with score above X) you can tell whether few or many people have it. I haven't figured out how to do the same with tag badges. Is that possible?

(tagging as support but maybe it's a feature request.)

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold

Comment: @approxiblue: Yeah... am I blind and missing the link? I guess I must be...

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use the [Tag Badges link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold) provided by [approxiblue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313109/how-can-i-check-how-many-people-have-gotten-a-certain-tag-badge#comment286068_313109).

If you need that data in an easy format you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/536923)

```sql
select name
     , case class 
       when 1 then 'Gold'
       when 2 then 'Silver'
       when 3 then 'Bronze'
       end as class
     , count(*) as [# awarded]
from badges
where tagbased = 1 
group by name, class
order by name, class desc
```

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated [once a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/152859).